# jira REST Plugin The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes

Tags: java, maven, jira, jira-plugin, jira-rest-java-api

I have read all of 3 questions, that whose asked before. I have try all described solutions for this questions. I asked google about this, and nothing helps me.

I'm new with JIRA development, and use official Atlassian tutorials.

So what the problem.

I need to add REST module to my plugin.

pom.xml dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.activeobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>activeobjects-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${ao.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.activeobjects</groupId>
            <artifactId>activeobjects-jira-spi</artifactId>
            <version>${ao.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- SAL, the Active Objects plugin uses SAL's API for transactions -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.sal</groupId>
            <artifactId>sal-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Google Collections, useful utilities for manipulating collections -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>14.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Add dependency on jira-core if you want access to JIRA implementation classes as well as the sanctioned API. -->
        <!-- This is not normally recommended, but may be required eg when migrating a plugin originally developed against JIRA 4.x -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jira.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- WIRED TEST RUNNER DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-plugins-osgi-testrunner</artifactId>
            <version>${plugin.testrunner.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2-atlassian-1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--FCK REST-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-multipart</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-apache-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-bundle</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Uncomment to use TestKit in your project. Details at https://bitbucket.org/atlassian/jira-testkit -->
        <!-- You can read more about TestKit at https://developer.atlassian.com/display/JIRADEV/Plugin+Tutorial+-+Smarter+integration+testing+with+TestKit -->
        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.jira.tests</groupId>
            <artifactId>jira-testkit-client</artifactId>
            <version>${testkit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.5</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-rest-module</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.atlassian.plugins.rest</groupId>
            <artifactId>atlassian-rest-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wink</groupId>
            <artifactId>wink-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.3-incubating</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

atlassian-plugin.xml part:

```
<web-resource key="taskautotimer-resources" name="taskautotimer Web Resources">
    <dependency>com.atlassian.auiplugin:ajs</dependency>
    <resource type="download" name="taskautotimer.css" location="/css/taskautotimer.css"/>
    <resource type="download" name="taskautotimer.js" location="/js/taskautotimer.js"/>
    <resource type="download" name="images/" location="/images"/>
    <context>taskautotimer</context>
  </web-resource>
  <!-- import from the product container -->
  <component-import key="applicationProperties" interface="com.atlassian.sal.api.ApplicationProperties"></component-import>
  <web-panel name="Time spent for task" i18n-name-key="timespentfortask.name" key="timespentfortask" location="atl.jira.view.issue.right.context" weight="1000">
    <description key="timespentfortask.description">The Time spent for task Plugin</description>
    <label key="timespentfortask.title"/>
    <context-provider class="com.miritec.jira.plugin.TimeSpentForTask"/>
    <resource name="view" type="velocity" location="timespentfortask.vm"/>
  </web-panel>
  <component-import key="ao" name="Active Objects service" interface="com.atlassian.activeobjects.external.ActiveObjects">
    <description>Component to access Active Objects functionality from the plugin</description>
  </component-import>
  <ao key="ao-module">
    <description>The module configuring the Active Objects service used by this plugin</description>
    <entity>com.miritec.jira.plugin.TSEntity</entity>
  </ao>
  <component key="tsservice" class="com.miritec.jira.plugin.TSServiceImpl" name="TSService" public="true" system="true">
    <interface>com.miritec.jira.plugin.TSService</interface>
  </component>
  <component key="tx-processor" name="Transactional Annotation Processor" class="com.atlassian.activeobjects.external.TransactionalAnnotationProcessor">
    <decription>Processes @Transactional annotations.</decription>
  </component>
  <rest name="TT Rest" i18n-name-key="tt-rest.name" key="tt-rest" path="/tasktimer" version="1.0">
    <description key="tt-rest.description">The TT Rest Plugin</description>
  </rest>
```

REST class and model:

```
package com.miritec.jira.plugin.rest;

import com.atlassian.plugins.rest.common.security.AnonymousAllowed;

import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

/**
 * A resource of message.
 */
@Path("/ttrest")
public class TTRest {

    @GET
    @AnonymousAllowed
    @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
    @Path("/msg")
    public Response getMessage()
    {
       return Response.ok(new TTRestModel("Hello World")).build();
    }
}

package com.miritec.jira.plugin.rest;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
public class TTRestModel {

    @XmlElement
    private String message;

    public TTRestModel() {
    }

    public TTRestModel(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

After all of [atlas-mvn clean install]/[atlas-run]/[removing proj/target/ content by hands]/[restarting jira] i still have same problem - 404(not found) page by /jira/rest/tasktimer/1.0/msg url and console stacktrace like this

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 22.08.2013 14:19:08 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.8-atlassian-11 03/22/2013 05:02 PM'
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2013-08-22 14:19:08,847 http-bio-2990-exec-13 ERROR admin 859x1912x1 1whoxol 192.168.1.18 /rest/tasktimer/1.0/msg [server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules] The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 22.08.2013 14:19:08 com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules <init>
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] SEVERE: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] 2013-08-22 14:19:08,848 http-bio-2990-exec-13 ERROR admin 859x1912x1 1whoxol 192.168.1.18 /rest/tasktimer/1.0/msg [atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager] Unable to create filter
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$InitializationException: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:149)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:112)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager.getFilter(DefaultServletModuleManager.java:389)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager.getFilters(DefaultServletModuleManager.java:213)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.DefaultRestServletModuleManager.getFilters(DefaultRestServletModuleManager.java:117)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:75)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilterInternal(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:26)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.doFilter(RestServletUtilsUpdaterFilter.java:40)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.applinks.core.rest.context.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:25)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.mywork.client.filter.ServingRequestsFilter.doFilter(ServingRequestsFilter.java:37)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsDispatcherFilter.java:60)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsSiteMeshFilter.java:92)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsMatcherFilter.java:56)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.labs.botkiller.BotKillerFilter.doFilter(BotKillerFilter.java:36)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.labs.httpservice.resource.ResourceFilter.doFilter(ResourceFilter.java:59)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.executeRequest(AccessLogFilter.java:103)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.accesslog.AccessLogFilter.doFilter(AccessLogFilter.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.security.xsrf.XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.doFilter(XsrfTokenAdditionRequestFilter.java:54)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.steps.ChainedFilterStepRunner.doFilter(ChainedFilterStepRunner.java:87)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.remotable.plugin.module.permission.ApiScopingFilter.doFilter(ApiScopingFilter.java:62)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.SecurityFilter.doFilter(SecurityFilter.java:234)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.security.auth.trustedapps.filter.TrustedApplicationsFilter.doFilter(TrustedApplicationsFilter.java:98)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.seraph.filter.BaseLoginFilter.doFilter(BaseLoginFilter.java:169)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.JiraLoginFilter.doFilter(JiraLoginFilter.java:70)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:46)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.oauth.serviceprovider.internal.servlet.OAuthFilter.doFilter(OAuthFilter.java:55)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.servlet.RestSeraphFilter.doFilter(RestSeraphFilter.java:40)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter$1.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:66)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.prettyurls.filter.PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.doFilter(PrettyUrlsCombinedMatchDispatcherFilter.java:61)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.doFilter(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:74)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.IteratingFilterChain.doFilter(IteratingFilterChain.java:42)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:77)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.doFilter(ServletFilterModuleContainerFilter.java:63)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.johnson.filters.AbstractJohnsonFilter.doFilter(AbstractJohnsonFilter.java:71)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.handleRewrite(RuleChain.java:176)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleChain.doRules(RuleChain.java:145)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriter.processRequest(UrlRewriter.java:92)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter.doFilter(UrlRewriteFilter.java:394)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilterInternal(GzipFilter.java:80)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.gzipfilter.GzipFilter.doFilter(GzipFilter.java:51)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.jira.web.filters.gzip.JiraGzipFilter.doFilter(JiraGzipFilter.java:55)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at  ... much more
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] Caused by: com.sun.jersey.api.container.ContainerException: The ResourceConfig instance does not contain any root resource classes.
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.RootResourceUriRules.<init>(RootResourceUriRules.java:99)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:1298)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.access$700(WebApplicationImpl.java:169)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:775)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl$13.f(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:771)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter$JerseyOsgiServletContainer.initiate(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:184)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:318)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:373)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:710)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.initServletContainer(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:99)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugins.rest.module.RestDelegatingServletFilter.init(RestDelegatingServletFilter.java:64)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.filter.DelegatingPluginFilter.init(DelegatingPluginFilter.java:43)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager$LazyLoadedFilterReference.create(DefaultServletModuleManager.java:442)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.plugin.servlet.DefaultServletModuleManager$LazyLoadedFilterReference.create(DefaultServletModuleManager.java:427)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference$Sync.run(LazyReference.java:321)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   at com.atlassian.util.concurrent.LazyReference.getInterruptibly(LazyReference.java:143)
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer]   ... 178 more
```

middle part of trace is cut, bcz of too long
Please, help me to solve this problem. Thanks in advance.

url /jira/rest/tasktimer/1.0/ttrest/msg same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem is solved. after updating atlas sdk to last version, recreating plugin with rest module first and downgrading AO version to 0.19.7 all looks fine. downgrading AO is important

Answer (score 0):

for me worked to change javax.xml.bind version to 2.3.0

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
```